# Предложенные записи в группе ВКонтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как получить список предложенных записей в группе Вконтакте,с помощью VK API. Гуглил, смотрел документацию ,ничего не нашел.

Может, кто знает ,подскажите.

Comment: В официальной документации всё есть https://vk.com/dev/wall.get

Comment: @andreymal , дак я искал, ничего не нашел ,чтобы получить данные об предложенной записи..

Comment: Откройте страницу по ссылке выше, нажмите Ctrl+F и в появившемся поле поиска введите «предлож»

Comment: @andreymal , извините, не увидел.. Там нужно было указать filter => suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения предложенных записей в `VK API`, из метода `wall.get`, нужно добавить в параметр `filter` значение `suggests`.

После чего, получим ответ:

```
Array
(
    [count] => 1 // количество записей
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [from_id] => 451757535 // Id отправителя
                    [owner_id] => -167683020 // Id группы
                    [date] => 1534851469
                    [marked_as_ads] => 0
                    [post_type] => suggest
                    [text] => QWERTY123 // Текст
                    [can_publish] => 1
                    [can_delete] => 1
                    [post_source] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => vk
                        )

                    [comments] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 0
                            [can_post] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```